# Can selenium be used for testing code written in react js and node js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an application called page-designer whose front-end(ui) is written in react js and the back-end Api part of it is written in node js.I want to know if selenium can be used as a tool for testing this application.

For example, i have an API for deleting a view based on its viewid-

```
const models = require('./../../models')

module.exports = delete_views = (req, res) => {
    console.log('alksjdklas')
    const {id,folder_id} = req.body;

     if(folder_id)
{
models.views.destroy({where : {folder_id:folder_id}})
.then((view)=>{
 res.status(200).send({message:'Views for folderid deleted sucessfully'})

}
)
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.status(401).send({
            message:'Unauthorized operation',err
        })
    })

}

else{
 models.views.destroy({where : {id:id}})
    .then((view)=>{

  res.status(200).send({message:'View deleted sucessfully'})
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.status(401).send({
            message:'Unauthorized operation',err
        })
    })


}


}
```

react js code for calling the delete_view api-

```
async deleteView(e){
  debugger
  console.log(this.state.viewid)
  const id=this.state.viewid
  console.log(this.state.viewid)
  let folder_id = null;
  await request(APIURL + '/views/' + 'delete_view', 'POST', {  id,folder_id })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("view successfully deleted")
        window.location.reload();
        //this.props.history.push('/');
       // this.setState({ contextmenu: null })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.setState({ alert: true, alertMessage: ["danger", "something went wrong"] })
        setTimeout(function () {
          this.setState({ alert: false, alertMessage: [] })
        }, 2000);
      })
      console.log(this.state.contextmenu)
      this.setState({ contextmenu: null })
      console.log(this.state.contextmenu)
}
```

So how do i test this using the selenium tool?I mean how do i write a test case for this? I am a little lost and confused.A little help and guidance in the right direction would be helpful.Please help.

Comment: Selenium is for testing end user interactions, more like system testing. You define a workflow (e.g. click a button, save a form), and then selenium automates this. Testing code is easier, and you can just define test cases in a separate module.

Comment: so in my example the delete operation happens when i right click a particular folder and click the delete option in the context menu.So this can be automated in selenium right?

Comment: Yes, this can be done with selenium.

Comment: ok i have started using selenium IDE as i dont want to write code for testing functionality.But in selenium IDE if an exception occurs when a button is clicked the selenium does not detect these errors/exceptions.It simply says test completed.